# How do I get a job without knowing Dutch? Would it be possible in one month? How much money will I need?

Tags: netherlands, working

I'm from Spain, 24 years old, Marketing + Tourism degree, some experience as receptionist in several hotels, fluent in Spanish, English and an intermediate level of German. I want to find a job in the Netherlands, especially close to Rotterdam or Delft.

My perfect job would be an for an eco-friendly business where I can keep learning about marketing and get some ideas for the Spanish market... Anyway for the first month I would be quite happy just having a job, as a waiter or cleaning service, I don't care...

Can someone give a couple tips?

Comment: Have you searched for companies that meet your criteria (location, ecology, business sector)? Have you asked them about work?

Comment: When I lived in Amsterdam in the early part of the previous decade, there was a fairly active job market for people who did not speak Dutch, though the quality of the jobs wasn't great.